# Ember Mirage - Not able to capture the response

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli-mirage

A newbie to ember, I am trying to simulate the API server using ember-cli-mirage. I am creating a request from `account.js` through `store` but the response is not something I expect.

```
## /app/routes/account.js

import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default Route.extend({
  store: service(),

  model() {
    this.store.findAll('accounts').then(response => {
      console.log(response)
    });
    // return this.store.findAll('accounts');
  }
});



## /app/mirage/config.js

export default function () {
  this.get('/accounts', (schema) => {
    return {
      data: [
        {
          firstName: 'John'
        }
      ]
    };
  }, {timing: 2000});
}
```

This is the response I get,
[image]

Is there anything missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're logging `response` which is actually the return value of `store.findAll`, rather than the HTTP response from Mirage.

`store.findAll` wraps up the HTTP request/response logic, and actually responds with an instance of an Ember Data model, or an array of models. In your case since you called `findAll`, the response is an array of Ember Data models.

If you want to see the details of Mirage's response, check your console for something like `Mirage: 200 OK for GET /accounts`. You should be able to expand that to see the details of the request and response that Mirage handled.

Comment: `$.getJSON('/accounts').then(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });` is returning expected data but 
`this.store.findAll('accounts').then(data => {
   console.log(data.get('length'));
});` is `0` and `data.get('firstObject')` is `undefined`. Could you please let me know what is the right way?

Comment: @moustacheman Where you able to solve this issue? Did you try logging the data and see?